# Disabling cache in asyncpg

Tags: python, postgresql, asynchronous, caching, asyncpg

I want to disable cache in asyncpg+postgresql to get timely results from the database and not outdated ones. However, I encounter an issue that doesn't allow me to do so:

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'AsyncConnection.execution_options' was never awaited
  async with engine.connect().execution_options(compiled_cache=None) \
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

My code is the following:

```
...
query = select(CardBase).where(CardBase.user_id==str(message.from_user.id))
current_cards = await retrieve_data_from_db(query, engine)
current_cards = current_cards.fetchone()
...
```

`retrieve_data_from_db:`

```
async def retrieve_data_from_db(query, engine):

""" Connects to the database and returns the results by a given query """

    async with engine.connect().execution_options(compiled_cache=None) \
        as conn:
        try:
            executed_query = await conn.execute(query)
            await conn.commit()
        except SQLAlchemyError as exc:
            print(exc)
            raise
        finally:
            await conn.close()
        return executed_query
```

Everything is awaited, I don't get what the problem is. So, how to write cache disabling using asyncpg+postgresql properly? Stating cache size in engine results in nothing.

```
engine = create_async_engine(f'postgresql+asyncpg://{username}:{password}'
                   f'@{host}/{database}?prepared_statement_cache_size=0',
                   pool_pre_ping=True,
                   echo=True,
                   )
```

Comment: `compiled_cache` is for generated SQL, not data. If you aren't see results from data committed by other transactions you may need to commit _before_ executing your query.

Comment: @snakecharmerb committing before executing the query results in nothing new. I am using this reference: https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/main/doc/build/core/connections.rst#disabling-or-using-an-alternate-dictionary-to-cache-some-or-all-statements

What is the proper way of putting this, then?

Comment: @snakecharmerb okay, I've finally rewritten the code to get no tracemalloc error, and it still uses cache. What is the point of the abovementioned piece of documentation then? How can it be fixed?

Comment: The cache is for the SQL statements generated by SQLAlchemy, which are stored as strings. Repeated generating the same strings for frequent queries is expensive, so they are cached. But to reiterate, what is being cached is the SQL statements as strings, not the results of executing queries.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Thanks for your explanation! I'd like to disable caching though, even if they are strings. How do I do that? It's not straightforward to me

Comment: The doc you linked to describes how to do it (`compiled_cache=None`). (Or [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html#disabling-or-using-an-alternate-dictionary-to-cache-some-or-all-statements) on the docs site).

Comment: /@snakecharmerb Please read the question carefully. That's exactly what I do and this results in an error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255362/discussion-between-ani-and-snakecharmerb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While SQLAlchemy does not maintain a cache of *results*, it does maintain a [cache of compiled SQL statements](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html#sql-compilation-caching). This is to prevent SQLAlchemy having to repeatedly convert the same SQLAlchemy statements into strings. It is this statement caching that emits messages like these when cache entries are created or retrieved:

```
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:[generated in 0.00012s] {}
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:[cached since 0.0008133s ago] {}
```

The size of the statement cache can be configured when the engine is created; setting it to zero disables statement caching *in SQLALchemy* globally.

```py
create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2:///test', query_cache_size=0)
```

Log output like this will then be emitted:

```
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:[caching disabled 0.00008s] {}
```

A statement cache may also be defined at the connection level, and setting it to `None` will prevent statement caching for that connection checkout.

```py
with engine.connect().execution_options(compiled_cache=None) as conn:
    conn.execute(sa.select(users))
```

If using an async engine, the execution options must be awaited separately to avoid the error in the question:

```py
async with engine.connect() as conn:
    await conn.execution_options(compiled_cache=None)
```

In this particular case, there is yet another statement cache to consider - that maintained by asyncpg. It can be disabled like this, according to the SQLAlchemy [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/postgresql.html#prepared-statement-cache):

```py
engine = create_async_engine("postgresql+asyncpg://user:pass@hostname/dbname?prepared_statement_cache_size=0")
```

Answer (score 0):

As @snakecharmerb pointed out in our discussion, the proper way of disabling cache is the following:

```
engine = create_async_engine(
"postgresql+asyncpg://souser:password@localhost/test",
echo=True,
query_cache_size=0
```

AND

```
engine.execution_options(compiled_cache=None)
```

(As I figured out, seems to work both with `session.begin()` and `engine.connect()`)

Answer (score -1):

To disable the the cache in sqlachemy properly when using asyncpg, you need to specify the `compiled_cache` option in the `execution_options`, try modifying your code;

```
async with engine.connect() as conn:
    try:
        executed_query = await conn.execution_options(compiled_cache=None).execute(query)
        await conn.commit()
    except SQLAlchemyError as exc:
        print(exc)
        raise
    finally:
        await conn.close()
    return executed_query
```